# Build string array from query resultset

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

What I'm trying to do is currently select all the username (2 for testing) and pass it into a string array.

However, the results I've tried so far all gotten me the first username and not all of them, so should I pass them into the string array, it probably has 1 value only.

Label1.Text is showing 1 result only.

I've tried executescalar, ExecuteNonQuery, executereader

```
  string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {

                    con.Open();
                    string queries = "select username from loginuser";
                    using (SqlCommand biju = new SqlCommand(queries, con))
                    {

                    SqlDataReader sda = null;
                    sda = biju.ExecuteReader();

                    while (sda.Read())
                    {
                        Label1.Text = sda["username"].ToString();
                    }

                  /*  sda = biju.ExecuteReader();
                        string a = Convert.ToString(sda);
                        Label1.Text = a; */
                        string message = string.Empty;
                        message = "list cleared for applicants to register again.";
                        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + message + "');", true);


                        // Three valid username/password pairs: Scott/password, Jisun/password, and Sam/password.
                        string[] users = new string[] { Label1.Text };
```

Comment: You're assigning every username to the same variable in your `while` loop, so when you come to add it to your array you only have the last one. You need to add you usernames to your array *inside* your `while` loop.

Comment: I'm not onto the string yet, displaying data on the label before passing into a string to see whether it's working first.
However, the label is only showing 1 data.
I've added the label.text inside the while loop , but it's still showing 1 data only.

Comment: The *last* name. This: `Label1.Text = sda["username"].ToString();` overwrites each time the content of the Label (why a Label as storage, here, then assign the reault to a variable?). Add a new string to the existing Text. It would be better to change `string[] users` to a `List<string>` and `.Add()` a new string (a name) in the loop. Also because this: `string[] users = new string[] { Label1.Text };` will give you back just one string in any case.

Comment: Then you would need `Label1.Text += sda["username"].ToString();`

Comment: Thanks all, this is solved! I just do a list.add in a loop , and then convert the list into the array. 
Thanks jimi and dale for helping me out :)